# java connection with DB H2

Tags: java

when you click on the search button, nothing happens

```
public class SearchAktion implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
        String search = searchJTField.getText();
        String sql = " SELECT * FROM car  WHERE model LIKE '%"+search+"%'";
        try {
            //conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
            state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            state.execute();
            refreshTable();
            resetForm();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}// end search action
```

Comment: `refreshTable(); resetForm();` Are you sure these have nothing to do with the fact that nothing happens? How do they work?

Comment: you could put the _DBConnector_  code  as well

Comment: Also you may want to use `executeQuery` instead of `execute` if you are interested in the result at all.

Comment: I think they work because I use them well when added to the table and deleted from it. I have three buttons: add, delete, and search. In the other addition and search, these two methods work

Comment: Ok, but where do you expect the result of that query to be after you executed it?

Comment: As already mentioned you need to use `executeQuery` and then you need to get your data from the returned `ResultSet`, see the [documentation for executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())